# Simple elasticsearch regexp

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to write a query to will give me all the documents where the field "id" is of the form: "SOMETHING-SOMETHING-4SOMETHING-SOMETHING-SOMETHING"

For instance, ab-ba-4a-b-a is a valid id.

I wrote this query

```
  "query": 
  {
    "regexp": 
    {
      "id":
      {
        "value": ".*-.*-4.*-.*-.*"
      }
    }
  }
```

It gets no hits. What's wrong with this? I can see many ids of this form.

Comment: What is the datatype of `id`?

Comment: The type is a string.

Comment: Could you also let me know which version of ES are you using?

Comment: I'm using 7.8, but the answer you wrote was great! you shouldnt have deleted it. it works

Comment: I've posted it once again, thought if you are using version 2.x, I may have to modify it a bit. But happy your query has been resolved!!

Comment: Thank you kind sir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `id` field is of type [`keyword`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/keyword.html) the regexp should be working fine.

However if it is of type [`text`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/text.html), notice how elasticsearch stores the token internally.

```
POST /_analyze
{
  "text": "abc-abc-4bc-abc-abc",
  "analyzer": "standard"
}
```

### Response:

```
{
  "tokens" : [
    {
      "token" : "abc",
      "start_offset" : 0,
      "end_offset" : 3,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 0
    },
    {
      "token" : "abc",
      "start_offset" : 4,
      "end_offset" : 7,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 1
    },
    {
      "token" : "4bc",
      "start_offset" : 8,
      "end_offset" : 11,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 2
    },
    {
      "token" : "abc",
      "start_offset" : 12,
      "end_offset" : 15,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 3
    },
    {
      "token" : "abc",
      "start_offset" : 16,
      "end_offset" : 19,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 4
    }
  ]
}
```

Notice that it breaks down the token `abc-abc-4abc-abc-abc` into 5 strings. Take a look at what [Analysis](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis.html) and [Analyzers](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analyzer-anatomy.html) are and how they are only applied on `text` fields.

However, keyword datatype has been created only for the cases where you do not want your text to be analyzed (i.e. broken into tokens and stored in inverted indexes) and stores the string value as it is internally.

Now just in case if your mapping is dynamic, ES by default creates two different fields for string values. a text and its keyword sibling, something like below:

```
{
    "mappings" : {
      "properties" : {
        "id" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

In that case, just apply the query you have on `id.keyword` field.

```
POST <your_index_name>/_search
{
  "query": {
    "regexp": {
      "id.keyword": ".*-.*-4.*-.*-.*"
    }
  }
}
```

Hope that helps!